# Very Simple C Strings: Storing and printing a string in a struct in C

Tags: c, string, struct, printf

I have a struct which I would like to store a string in:

```
#define MAXLINE 80 

struct HistoryElement
{
  int NumberOfCommandGiven;
  char command[MAXLINE];
};
```

As you can see, the array of characters called command is meant to store the string.

However, I am having trouble when trying to store such a string in a struct.

```
struct HistoryElement* History = malloc(historysize*sizeof(struct HistoryElement)); //Create an array of HistoryElements
char iBuffer[MAXLINE];
char *args[MAXLINE/2+1]; 
setup(iBuffer, args, &bgrnd); //Parses input string into iBuffer and args
//Add the command to history:
struct HistoryElement input;
input.NumberOfCommandGiven = numberofcommand; //this works fine.
strcpy(input.command, iBuffer); //<-- This is what must be wrong!
printf("input.command:  %s",input.command); //***TEST***
History[numberofcommand-1%historysize] = input;
```

The TEST case will only print the first word of any string, it does not include spaces.  So if the input command was "ls -l", then the test case will only print out "ls", whereas it should print "ls -l".  Why is it not picking up the *entire* line that is input by the user?

Comment: What does iBuffer contain? (Try printing it)

Comment: yup my guess is that the 'setup' function is doing the wrong thing. What did the debugger show (you did run it under a debugger didnt you)

Comment: iBuffer contains only the phrase "ls" and not "ls -l"

Comment: However, I can also make use the variable called args.  args contains 'ls' at position 0, and -l at position 1, etc.  BUT, i do not know how to convert this char * array, to a regular string.

Comment: Jeopardy Question: [What is an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: bgrnd is an integer, which determines whether or not to run the process (the command that the user is inputting) concurrently or not.  It does not have to do with the history.

Answer (score 0):

does args[] contain nul terminated strings?

then (If you decide to not fix the setup() function )

then the following should fix the problem.

```
// clear the destination to all NUL chars
memset( input.command, 0x00, sizeof input.command);

// loop until a args[i] entry begins with NUL char
int i;
while( args[i][0] )
{
    // append args[i] to end of string in input.command
    strcat(input.command, args[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This looks like very similar to what I was thinking and what i need, let me try.

Comment: If you are still there I would really appreciate any help with this code.  I am getting a segfault using it but it looks very similar to what I want.